# Importing Images in SQL Server Data Tools

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to create a report using SSDT.  I would like to include an image on the report, but I do not know how.

The image properties dialog box appears, and it asks for several pieces of information.  Firstly, it wants me to specify a tooltip, and I have no idea what that is.  Secondly, I am asked to specify if the image is external, embedded, or in the database.  I don't know what these three options mean.  I assume that external means getting the image from the desktop or C-drive.
Lastly, there is a dropdown box called "Use This".  I assume that this would be used to specify where the image can be found.  However, the dropdown list is blank.  Also, there is an expression button to the right of the box.  How can I use the expression dialog box to specify an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll most likely want to use an embedded image.

On my version of visual studio (2010) I see everything you described in your post but next to the expression button is an "Import..." button. This allows you to import a picture from the filesystem and embed it in the report.

Alternatively if you look in the "Report Data" window (which has all of the datasets and data sources, etc) there is a folder named "Images". You can right-click that folder and select "Add Image..." and this will also import images and embed them in the report definition.

Once you have the image embedded in the report you can select it from the "Use this" drop-down.

Just FYI about the other options you mentioned:

- Tooltip: this is the text that is displayed when the mouse hovers over the image
- Embedded images are actual stored in the report definition file, meaning they are deployed with the report and will increase the size of the RDL file. External images are from the filesystem and database images are stored as a binary column in the database.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you have a read of [How to: Add an Image (Reporting Services)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156388%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Stackoverflow expects people to have at least attempted to do some research and tackle the problem *before* asking questions on this site. It is clear from the questions above that the poster has not taken the time to read the available resources already published by the product vendor - there is no point in repeating material already available in a clear and concise form elsewhere.